# Inject 3rd party HTML (with scripts) in page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am rebranding my site with a header/footer HTML code from a partner (to make the site behave like it's rebranded).

Visually:

existing-website.com:

```
+---------------------+
|                     |
|       My site       |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

wrapped-website.com:

```
+---------------------+
|     Brand Header    |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|       My site       |     variable page height
|                     |
+---------------------+
|     Brand Footer    |
+---------------------+
```

The brand header and footer are blocks of HTML code, with inlined JS. And there is also another block of HTML with scripts and CSS. It using a version of jQuery and a part of their script is actually crashing by itself.

What I did: Inject their HTML in by normal pages servers-side + put all my scripts at the end of `<body>`

The structure looks like:

```
<head>
  [.. their head (CSS/JS) stuff as HTML ..]
  .. my CSS stuff ..
  [.. fixes for their CSS stuff ..]
</head>
<body>
  [.. their HTML header ..]
  .. my normal body ..
  [.. their HTML footer ..]
  .. my JS ..
</body>
```

Thus the only difference between the branded and non-branded site is that the branded-site **"switches on" the lines with brackets**.

NB:

- I put CSS fixes at the end of `head` to fix conflicts between their CSS and mine
- I put all my JS in the end so that it overrides other possible behavior from their JS stuff.

It seems to me it can work that way, but I'm wondering if it's a good/robust idea, knowing notably that their code (HTML/CSS/JS) can be updated.

I was also thinking about iframing my website. No need for the CSS fixes and no JS problem then! But then I want the iframe to be as high as needed (`height` corresponding to the total height of the page, even if the height is changing dynamically, see the schema above). I read that it's really hard to achieve.

Is there something I can enhance on what I did?
Or is it possible to achieve iframing my site correctly?
Or something else?

Comment: Does you site just consist of static files with all the processing handled client side, or are you also using a server side servlet/jsp of some kind?

Comment: i don't like the iframe idea much, but im not thrilled about the other options either...

Comment: @ZacWolf it's Django website. I use server-side code to inject the branding HTML pieces inside my "usual" pages

Comment: Well I don't use phython enough to know what html parser libraries are available, but since this environment does allow server side processing, then you can build a python script that will retrieve and parse the old page to pull out the header/footer html, and then inject that content into your new html file.  Anytime anyone asks for a page your code can see if there's been changes to the original, and then rebuild the new page, otherwise it just serves the new page.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the iframe the size of the container is actually pretty easy with css.

```
iframe{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
}
```

In comments you mentioned this was a Django site.  I'm just not familiar enough with that environment or with Python but after looking at their site, it does allow server side processing.  You can write a python script that will retrieve and parse the old page to pull out the header/footer html, and then inject that content into your new html file. Do you see the other site's content changing much that you would need to synchronize to?

Comment: I don't understand how your CSS: in my browser, this is just positioning the iframe on top left. I also tried with a containing div position:relative, same story.
Indeed I can do server-side processing, and I guess what you are describing in your ending paragraph is actually what I did until now, as I try to explain in the question.

Comment: I updated my question to make things clearer and explain what I already did

Comment: This CSS basically makes iFrame expand to fill its parent, so if an iFrame is the child of BODY, it should cause the iFrame to expand to fill the screen.  If it's a child of a div, then that div will need to have a height/width that the iFrame can expand into.  But like you said I think that's a red hearing in what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You would be best off to write a server side application that does the url pull of the old site's html, parse it, then replace their content tags, with your own.  There are ton of ways to do this, if the parent site changes often, then you'll either need to do the server query real time(not the best idea), or on some kind of schedule.